# Is it possible to get the mac addresses of all connected device in my home network?

Tags: java, android, mac-address

I wanted to create a personal app that can display who's at home now by detecting all the devices connected to the network. Is it possible?

Comment: You should study `java.net` package

Answer (score 0):

there are already routers that accept access from outside of your network and you can use that to get all the information you need.

If you want something better, you can write a program to run on your PC from home that will get all this information and sends them to you, and for this I would recommend you java and selenium